# Design view is not working in C++ Winforms in VS2017

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I've a Win forms C++ project originally developed in VS 2010. I've converted the solution to VS 2017. 
I'm not able to see the design view for any of the files. 
All the files just display with the "H" icon and opens as a code file only. 
I tried adding a new win form item to the project and its design view is working fine. 
I'm new to C++ and not able to figure it out.

I've added the screen shots below. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is how the old win form files displaying in solution explorer.

[image]

And this is the new form which I added. It opens with the design view.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the "File Type" in the property view of the file to either "C++ Form" or "C++ Control"?

Comment: `Menu/Build/Clear Solution` and then `Rebuild  solution`.  Select `Menu/View/Class View`